# SSIS Flat File Source Not Splitting Column by Comma

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file, dataflowtask

I have a flat file connector in SSIS but for some reason it is not splitting the commas into columns. I have the column delimiter set to comma and you can see in "Column 0" there is commas "," however it just doesn't want to split them. Has anyone come across this before? Any help would be amazing!

The file has a LF line terminators (UNIX way). Is this an issue for SSIS? There is an option I have selected.

[image]

Comment: Is there a text qualifier set?  e.g. double-quotes will delimit a string containing commas ("some, random, text") so that the string between the double-quotes will be treated as a single value.

Comment: There is no text qualifier set however even adding a double quotes to the text qualifier box does not fix the issue :/

Comment: Have you opened the source file to verify it's in the correct format?  There seems to be two blank rows and then some text like 'something Fields' in the image in the question.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely formatted correctly, when I open in excel, it looks fine :S

Comment: Is it an excel document then?  Try exporting it from excel into a tab delimited file and import that.

Comment: No, it is a CSV file. Need it to be automated as i'll be using foreach loop  containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, needed to remove a few rows to get the headers to split, using the "Header row to skip" entry. Thanks for all your help!

[image]